# Android APK Certificates - what fields are required and what if that info changes?

Tags: android, certificate, apk, signing

This seems pretty basic but I can't find the info I'm looking for anywhere, particularly with regard to Android apps.

I am creating my release key (self-signed) and I am asked for lots of info:

- **First and Last Name:** (OK; not likely to change)
- **Organizational Unit:** (Is this one's "business name"?)
- **Organization:** (How's this different from the "Unit" above?)
- **City or Locality:** (This may change...)
- **State or Province:** (Also may change...)
- **Country Code (XX):** (OK; not likely to change)

With that in mind, I've got two basic questions about self-signed certificates used to distribute Android apps:

1. **On creation, can I leave any of these fields EMPTY, particularly the ones that are likely to change? Or is that forbidden?** (The big question.)
2. **What if I want to change a given field *later*? Does that mean creating a new key and having everyone reinstall the app to ever upgrade again, even if I have the original key?** (Seems to be the case, judging by what little I *have* found.)

Thanks in advance!

---

**Edit:** More info on #1 above: if this is anything like SSL certs, then the Name, Organization and Country should be sufficient. But IS that the case? Pros and cons of leaving any/all the other fields blank? I can't be the only one who's wondered about this in terms of apps... and the Android docs I've read so far aren't helping clarify this.

For #2, it appears that changing the certificate means regenerating it, and signing with that new cert doesn't avoid the Market problem (it's like a whole new app, even if you sign with both the new AND old certs). So it's all the more important to get it right (yet sufficiently generic in case you move) the first time you sign the app.

Comment: you must check out this.
http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html

Comment: I did, repeatedly, before I asked this question. Do you see something I missed that answers either of these questions?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The content of these fields are actually pretty irrelevant and are not generally seen by anyone other than you. You can leave empty fields wherever keytool will allow without consequence later.

Once you sign an apk with a keystore and upload it to the Android Market, you cannot sign that same package with another keystore. This is obviously done to prevent someone else from replacing your app with another.

For my keystore I put my personal information in it, set the expiration date for 999 years in the future and keep it safe and backed up.

Comment: I think that covers it then. I wasn't sure if there was any legal issue with it... if there was then it'd be a nightmare in the present scheme since you can never update the cert, even by bridging it (signing with old and new for a period of time until switching to the new one altogether). If one can sign with the old cert + a new cert it proves chain of custody. A thief today would need only to keep using the old cert). This is simplified but the bottom line is, certificate updates should be possible (and indeed must be in the world of SSL) but that isn't implemented in the Market.

Comment: Nine years later, it's still very difficult to come across relevant information - very happy to have found this question and this answer! @Michael or anyone, are you aware of any _official_ documentation stating whether (or that) the fields are optional and whether (or that) it's acceptable to write any old values in them?

Answer (score 16):

To strictly answer the question about which fields are optional: actually, *all* fields are optional. The only requirement is that you provide at least one (even if it's just the country code).

Here's Android Studio's explanation:
[image: Android Studio displaying an error message]

It reads:

> At least one Certificate issuer field is required to be non-empty

Sure enough, with some testing, I confirmed that only one field is required.

As answered by Michael, once your app is published, you can **never change it**.

Comment: and even that is not required at least when I was directed to use Java's keytool directly by react-native

Comment: @1mike12 Can you give a pointer to how to use keytool to do this job? Part of the complication for me is knowing all of what this wizard actually does -- creates a keystore, creates a key to go in it, creates a cert, signs the key with the cert? Anything else?

Comment: The documentation goes in to much more detail than what I could offer here: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore. The keytool itself is documented here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/keytool.html